# General Python Errors on Yosemite

Tags: python, macos, eval, osx-yosemite

I'm very new to python (doing it as a first year level course at university) and I installed WindIDE as was recommended by the course convenors, as well as a Python 3.4.2 package for Mac OS 10.6. I'm running Yosemite on 13" Macbook Air, if that information is at all helpful.

The main problem I have encountered, is that I seem to get errors thrown at me from all angles when I attempt to execute code of almost any kind. At first, I attributed the problem to me making syntax and logic errors, but I quickly came to the conclusion that that was not the case, since even the model examples that my lecturer provided for us wouldn't run.

Below is an example of the code that I have tried to run, as well as the output:

```python
number_1 = eval (input ("Enter the first number: "))
number_2 = eval (input ("Enter the second number: "))

sum = number_1 + number_2

print ("The sum of the numbers",number_1,"and",number_2,"is",sum)



Enter the first number: 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/damonlurie/Documents/CSC1005F/Examples/Python Basics/add.py", line 5, in 0
TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string or code object
```

I'm obviously not sure why this is happening

Answer (score 1):

`input()` already uses `eval()` on the input. You can either get rid of `eval()`, or replace `input()` with `raw_input()`.

Use

```
number_1 = input("Enter the first number: ")
number_2 = input("Enter the second number: ")
sum = number_1 + number_2
```

or

```
number_1 = eval(raw_input("Enter the first number: "))
number_2 = eval(raw_input("Enter the second number: "))
sum = number_1 + number_2
```

Answer (score 0):

Macintosh computers come preinstalled with an Apple specific port of Python 2. In all likelyhood, your script is executed as a Python 2 script rather than the Python 3 you installed. Try configuring as described in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jmjTAXbH-SA) video.